# Multiple Ajax Async call

Tags: jquery, ajax, asynchronous, synchronization

I have list of lib name from the name I want fetch the author name. for this I  made each loop on library name and make async call. I want return all the author name with library name once the call was end. 
While I try with Async call it return the call back before the call was successes. so I have try to return the callback in success but now the call back was return once the first request completed.
I have try with sync call but it block the user interface. so what is the best method to do that. My code

```
function FetchLibAuthorID(LibCollection, callback) {
$.each(LibCollection, function (key, value) {
    $.ajax({
        url: value.MetadataURI + '?$select=schemaXml',
        type: "GET",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
        success: function (data) {
            var listProperties = schemaXml2Json(data.d.SchemaXml);
            LibCollection[key].AuthorID = listProperties.Author;
            LibCollection[key].RootFolder = listProperties.RootFolder;
        },
        error: function (data2) {
            alert('error');
        }
    });
});
return callback(LibCollection);
```

}

Comment: add a property  async : true

Comment: By default Ajax call are async only. am I correct? then if any specific reason to add that property

Answer (score 0):

```
var libCollection = [{ MetadataURI: "url1" }, { MetadataURI: "url2" }];

function loadLibrary(complete) {
    if (libCollection.length === 0) {
        complete();
        return;
    }

    var lib = libCollection.pop();
    $.ajax({
        url: lib.MetadataURI + '?$select=schemaXml',
        type: "GET",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
        complete: function (data) {
            var listProperties = schemaXml2Json(data.d.SchemaXml);
            LibCollection[key].AuthorID = listProperties.Author;
            LibCollection[key].RootFolder = listProperties.RootFolder;

            loadLibrary(complete);
        }
    });
};

// call the function

loadLibrary(function() {
    alert("all libraries have been loaded")
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        function FetchLibAuthorID(LibCollection, callback) {
    var count=0;
        $.each(LibCollection, function (key, value) {
    count++;
            $.ajax({
                url: value.MetadataURI + '?$select=schemaXml',
                type: "GET",
                headers: { "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
                success: function (data) {
    count--;
                    var listProperties = schemaXml2Json(data.d.SchemaXml);
                    LibCollection[key].AuthorID = listProperties.Author;
                    LibCollection[key].RootFolder = listProperties.RootFolder;
                },
                error: function (data2) {
                    alert('error');
                }
            });
        });

    while(count>0)
    {

    }
  return callback(LibCollection);
}
```